# SwiftUI macOS sidebar list-based navigation with pop

Tags: macos, swiftui

I am trying to create the following design on macOS.

- Sidebar navigation.
- Items are drawn from a dynamic list, with additional fixed Search and Create New options.
- The Content area should show a detail view if an Item is selected, a search form if Search is selected, an input form if Create New is selected, and be blank if nothing is selected.
- The Content area contains a Close button which should clear the menu selection and turn the Content area blank.

```
+------------+-----------------------+
| Search     |                       |
| Create New |                       |
| ---        |                       |
| Item 1     |        Content        |
| Item 2     |                       |
| ...        |                       |
| Item n     |        [Close]        |
+------------+-----------------------+
```

I've had success creating each of these in isolation but no luck combining them. Binding the `List`'s `selection` enables the Close button to work. Putting a `ForEach` inside a `List` allows adding the two fixed list options, but stops the `selection` from working.

Is there a way in SwiftUI to achieve this kind of layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by making use of `tag`, which allowed selection to work when there are arbitrary items in the List alongside dynamic ones:

```swift
struct Item: Identifiable {
  let id: Int
  let name: String
}

struct SidebarView: View {
  var items: [String] = [Item(id: 1, name: "Item 1"), Item(id: 2, name: "Item 2")]
  @State var selectionId: Int? = -1

  var body: some View {
    List {
      NavigationLink(destination: SearchView(), tag: -1, selection: $selectionId) {
        Text("Search")
      }
      NavigationLink(destination: CreateView(), tag: -2, selection: $selectionId) {
        Text("Create New")
      }
      Section(header: Text("Item List")) {
        ForEach(items, id: \.id) { item in
          NavigationLink(destination: ViewItem(item), tag: item.id, selection: $selectionId) {
            Text(item.name)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A lot's of code below, but try it on your Xcode. Search, Add new and Close buttons are functional, but there are only integers placeholdering your real content. The selection also works with no problem. The layout is also responsive to window resizing (window min-width 500px and min-height 300px).

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var openItem: Int? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            SidebarView(openItem: self.$openItem)
            SelectedContent(openItem: self.$openItem)
        }
    }
}

struct SidebarView: View {
    @Binding var openItem: Int?
    
    @State var search: String = ""
    @State var items: [Int] = Array(1...20)
    
    var searchedItems: [Int] {
        if self.search == "" { return self.items }
        var results: [Int] = []
        for item in self.items {
            if String(item).contains(self.search) { results.append(item) }
        }
        return results
    }
    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Search...", text: self.$search)
                .padding([.horizontal, .top])
            
            Button(action: {
                self.items.append(self.items.count+1)
            }) {
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                    Text("Create new")
                }
            }
            
            Divider()
            
            List {
                ForEach(self.searchedItems, id: \.self) { item in
                    Button(action: {
                        self.openItem = item
                    }) {
                        Text("Item \(item)")
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 200)
    }
}


struct SelectedContent: View {
    @Binding var openItem: Int?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack { Spacer() }
            if self.openItem == nil {
                Text("Choose item on the left")
                    .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .semibold))
                    .foregroundColor(Color(.secondaryLabelColor))
            } else {
                VStack {
                    Text("Item \(self.openItem!) opened!")
                        .font(.system(size: 20))
                    Button(action: {
                        self.openItem = nil
                    }) {
                        HStack {
                            Image(systemName: "xmark")
                            Text("Close")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is how it looks like when no item is selected:
[image: product of the code above]
And here is how it looks like when you have selected an item:
[image: product of the code above]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I’ve awarded you the bounty.